# Why this.props.children return this component?

Tags: reactjs

This is the correct usage? "this.props.children.props.children"?

```
{ React.cloneElement(this.props.children.props.children, this.props) }
```

this.props.children shows this component :O. What I forgot?

ESLint expected 'children' is missing in props validation but i have

```
myClass.protoType =  {
  children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
};
```

Comment: explain what you  intend to do by `{ React.cloneElement(this.props.children.props.children, this.props) }`. Otherwise, it is not `protoType ` but `propTypes`

Comment: @DamienLeroux Thx it was my misstake

Answer (score 0):

I use this and works fine for me:

React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props);